# In CSOM - Utility.ResolvePrincipal not returning null - For any user it is resolving

Tags: csom

I am writing code to get Display name based on UserEmail. But even if i give junk email also it "ClientResult principal" not returning null. This is my code.  If i give correct email id - i am getting correct displayname.   But if i give wrong email id some thing not exists also it is resolving and returning displayname as same email id. Please correct by code.

ClientResult principal = Utility.ResolvePrincipal(ctx, web, searchEmail, PrincipalType.User, PrincipalSource.All,null, true);
                        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                        if (principal .Value!=null)  // This never be null in my code                  TitleFromEmail= principal.Value.DisplayName.ToString();

Please help to resolve?

Comment: Did you try checking the "IsResolved" property value for true/false or PrincipalId == -1?